# Select rows that are not between dates (reservation)

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have a car rental script. I have the cars in a cars table. I keep all the reservation information in a reservation table. Reservation table has from and until date fields as well as car_id field.

For example: car_id: 14, from="2014-06-24", until="2014-07-24".

I am trying to write a query to fetch all cars that are **not** reserved between given dates. I have tried a couple of tricks like inner join and not exists etc.

So, say I am trying to fetch the available cars between dates "2014-06-24" and "2014-08-24".

For simplifying purposes to make my problem clear: selecting **reserved** cars using this query doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE from >= '2014-06-24' AND until <= '2014-08-24'
```

Because a car might be booked from '2014-06-30' until '2014-09-15'. Since the until date is not greater than or equal to until date in the query the car doesn't show up as reserved.

I hope you can understand my point. Thanks in advance.

I found the query that I was looking for thanks to Marc B's answer:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE cars.id = reservation.car_id AND until >= '2014-06-24' AND from <= '2014-08-24')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following cases. You've got your already reserved dates A and B, and your two dates that you're trying to book for, P and Q. That means the following conditions can be true:

```
A B P Q    date comes AFTER 'already booked'
A P B Q  * dates overlap
A P Q B  * dates are entirely overlapped
P A Q B  * dates overlap
P Q A B    date comes BEFORE 'already booked'
```

The entries with `*` are the ones you're interested in, and once you crunch all the comparisons and logic down, you end up with

```
P <= B && Q >= A
```