# SQL - Find Available Slots Within Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `venue` (
    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `property_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `venue_available` (
    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `venue_id` INT(100) NOT NULL,
    `day` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `from_time` TIME NOT NULL,
    `to_time` TIME NOT NULL,
    `lead_time_in_minutes` INT(11)
);
CREATE TABLE `venue_unavailable` (
    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `venue_id` INT(100) NOT NULL,
    `from_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `to_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `venue_reservation` (
    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `venue_id` INT(100) NOT NULL,
    `start_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `end_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I want to find properties having venues available from 25th Aug(Sat) to 27th August (Mon) from 10am to 3pm

Here is the SQL query I tried

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name AS property_name,
    v.name AS venue_name
FROM
    venue v
LEFT JOIN
    property p ON v.property_id = p.id
-- venue_available
LEFT JOIN
    venue_available va_0 ON va_0.venue_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN
    venue_available va_1 ON va_1.venue_id = v.id
WHERE 1 = 1
-- venue_available
    AND (
        (va_0.day = 'sat' AND va_0.from_time <= '2018-08-25 10:00:00' AND va_0.to_time >= '2018-08-25 15:00:00') AND
        (va_1.day = 'sun' AND va_1.from_time <= '2018-08-26 10:00:00' AND va_1.to_time >= '2018-08-26 15:00:00')
    )
-- venue_unavailable
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM venue_unavailable vu WHERE '2018-08-25 10:00:00' <= vu.to_datetime AND '2018-08-26 15:00:00' >= vu.from_datetime)
GROUP BY
    p.id;
```

The problem with the current query is, the condition for `venue_available` in SQL query seems to work correctly, but when I add the condition for `venue_unavailable` it returns me the empty result, however based on the data I am expecting 1 result.

Here is the link to SQL fiddle, if you want to play around with schema and fixtures

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33d60f/10

Here is what I am trying to do
1. Get the list of all properties (not venues)
2. List the property only if one or more venue is available after checking with

- venue_available
- venue_unavailable
- venue_reservation

Can you help me with how to go about this?x

Thank you.

**UPDATE1**

I followed the following post to determine overlapping dates in venue_unavailable [Select rows that are not between dates (reservation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375487/select-rows-that-are-not-between-dates-reservation)

Comment: Maybe you have mixed up `<=` and `>=` or `to_` and `from_` ? Because if you change them to each other, it works.

Comment: Let me check this @MichaelO.

Comment: Can you delete (or answer and accept) if this is now resolved.

Comment: Why do people downvote without caring to explain? I feel SO should have a comment box for people downvoting, atleast this way, we know the reason of downvoting and perhaps a chance to improve. Or is it that people want to randomly vote for no reason.

Comment: I agree there should be a comment required to explain downvotes. This idea has been proposed many times but it's always rejected by Stack Overflow. There's an answer explaining their reasons here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so the way I solved it is using sub query which is working now.

I am now using the WHERE clause with something like this

```
WHERE v.id NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM provider_block pb WHERE :start_datetime <= pb.to_date AND :end_datetime >= pb.from_date)
```

This seems to do the job for now.